# Issues switching between different versions of Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, compatibility, excel-2016

We recently had a new employee join our (very small) company, and he is using Excel 2010 while the rest of the office uses Excel 2016.

When he attempts to run a macro which draws a chart, he gets an error message that says:

> Compile Error - Method or Data member not Found

However, this error message doesn't appear when I run the exact same macro in Excel 2016.

The line of code which appears to be throwing up a problem is the following:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText2
```

Has anyone come across this problem before? And is there any quick solution, besides the obvious of switching him to Excel 2016 like the rest of us?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use SeriesCollection for pre 2013. That should work across all versions.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you